# Filling up columns equally in iText(2) MultiColumnText

Tags: java, itext, itextpdf

I'm using a MultiColumnText element to layout out elements in three columns. It now looks like this:

```
some text on the first page...

Element1     Element4
Element2     Element5
Element3     Element6

-pagebreak-

Element7     Element12
Element8
Element9
Element10
Element11
```

As you see, one the second page, it first fills up the first column and then starts the second column. I want it to be equally distributed over the 2 columns, so it looks like this:

```
some text on the first page... 

Element1     Element4
Element2     Element5
Element3     Element6

-pagebreak-

Element7   Element10
Element8   Element11
Element9   Element12
```

I know that I can set the height of the MultiColumnText in the constructor, but I don't know the total height of all the elements at construction time. Any Ideas?

Comment: *I don't know the total height of all the elements at construction time.* - then receive the elements for the current page first and construct thereafter.